# Merge overlapping intervals - it doesn't work properly for negative numbers

Tags: c++

I've tried to do this exercise myself but I couldn't make it work properly for negative intervals.

Then I implemented the version from geeksforgeeks and I get the same thing. Here's the logic behind it:

```
1. Sort the intervals based on increasing order of 
    starting time.
2. Push the first interval on to a stack.
3. For each interval do the following
   a. If the current interval does not overlap with the stack 
       top, push it.
   b. If the current interval overlaps with stack top and ending
       time of current interval is more than that of stack top, 
       update stack top with the ending  time of current interval.
4. At the end stack contains the merged intervals.
```

```
.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include "Header.h"


bool functieComparareIntervalCrescator(Interval interval1, Interval interval2)
{
    return interval1.lo < interval2.lo;
}

void citire(int& n, Interval vectorIntervale[])
{
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        vectorIntervale[i].citire();
    }
}

void afisareStack(std::stack<Interval> stivaIntervale)
{
    int n = stivaIntervale.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << stivaIntervale.top().lo << " " << stivaIntervale.top().hi << std::endl;
        stivaIntervale.pop();
    }
}

void determinareReuniune(int n, Interval vectorIntervale[])
{
std::sort(vectorIntervale, vectorIntervale + n, functieComparareIntervalCrescator);
    std::stack<Interval> stivaIntervale;
    stivaIntervale.push(vectorIntervale[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (vectorIntervale[i].lo > stivaIntervale.top().lo && vectorIntervale[i].lo < stivaIntervale.top().hi)
        {
            if (vectorIntervale[i].hi > stivaIntervale.top().hi)
            {
                stivaIntervale.top().hi = vectorIntervale[i].hi;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            stivaIntervale.push(vectorIntervale[i]);
        }
    }
    afisareStack(stivaIntervale);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    Interval vectorIntervale[100];
    citire(n, vectorIntervale);
    determinareReuniune(n, vectorIntervale);
}
```

```
header.cpp
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>

void Interval::citire()
{
    std::cin >> lo >> hi;
}
```

```
#pragma once

struct Interval {
    int lo, hi;
    void citire();
};
```

For the input:

```
5
2 4 1 3 5 8 10 12 6 9
```

I get the correct answer.

However, if I change the input to negative numbers, like

```
5
-2 -4 -1 -3 -5 -8 -10 -12 -6 -9
```

the output is

```
-6 -9
-10 -12
-5 -8 
-1 -3
-2 -4
```

which is definitely not right.

Here is the implementation from GeeksForGeeks, which is pretty similar to mine.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/

If you copy and paste their code, it still doesn't work properly.

How can I fix my code so it can also work properly for negative intervals?

Thanks.

//edit:
I forgot to add the sort part. I've added it into my code and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read input you do:

```
void Interval::citire()
{
    std::cin >> lo >> hi;
}
```

And you assume that `lo < hi`. However, your input with negatives is:

```
5
-2 -4 -1 -3 -5 -8 -10 -12 -6 -9
```

And all intervals have first the larger number and then the smaller one. Either your input is invalid and it should be:

```
5
-4 -2 -3 -1 -8 -5 -12 -10 -9 -6
```

Or you need to sort the bounds after reading input:

```
void Interval::citire()
{
    int a,b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    lo = std::min(a,b);
    hi = std::max(a,b);
}
```

Or (suggested by Jarod42):

```
void Interval::citire()
{
    int a,b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::tie(lo,hi) = std::minmax(a,b);
}
```

Comment: I forgot about sorting the array. I also added std::sort in determinareReuniune, but I still don't get the expected result.

Comment: Possibly `std::tie(lo, hi) = std::minmax(a, b);`.

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu positive numbers arent substantially different from negatives and I didn't find a place in your code where you distinguish them. What exaclty did you change? You don't need `std::sort` to "sort" two numbers

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu you can show me your updated `Interval::citire` here: https://godbolt.org/, then maybe I can comment, but without seeing your code I don't know what you did

Comment: I've added std::sort into determinareReuniune, so my intervals are sorted in ascending order (by a/left side of the interval to be more clear). I didn't change anything else.

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu not sort the intervals, sort `lo` and `hi` of each interval (as I showed in the answer)

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu there is already a call to `std::sort` in `determinareReuniune` in the code in your question, so I don't understand what you changed

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu please do not change the question after you received answers. In this case it isnt a big problem (because I am not refering to that sorting), but I did cause some confusion

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I'm sorry for that. I just forgot to add that part and I thought it might be needed. Now I understand :) thanks for your answer